# Nginx in UDP load balancing continue to send to an unreachable upstream server

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, logstash

I use Nginx to load balance traffic coming from udp syslog sources to logstash

Configuration :

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1000000;
# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

#UDP syslog load balancing
stream {

    server {
        listen     514 udp;
        proxy_pass logstash_servers;
        proxy_timeout   1s;
        proxy_responses 0;
        proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
    }

    upstream logstash_servers {
        server 192.168.2.90:514 fail_timeout=10s;
        server 192.168.2.95:514 fail_timeout=10s;
    }


}
```

It works fine but if one of my upstream logstash server is down, Nginx does not take it into account and I receive the half of message on the remaining upstream logstash server.

How can I tell to Nginx to use only the remaining logstash server if one is down ?